# How can I get all xhr calls in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, xmlhttprequest, puppeteer

I am using `puppeteer` to load a web page.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', (request) => {
    console.log(request.url())
    request.continue();
    ...
  }
}
await page.goto(
    'https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195',
    { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' },
  );
```

I set the request interception to `true` and log all requests urls. The requests I logged is a lot less than the requests when I load the url in chrome browser. 
At least there is one request `https://www.onthehouse.com.au/odin/api/compositeSearch` which can be found in chrome dev tool console but not show in above code.

I wonder how I can log all requests?

Comment: Isn't your Chrome DevTools Network records some 3rd party requests (e.g. Chrome addons) as well? I compared your script's requests and the page's network traffic in Chrome and for me they match in 100%. I see no more requests in Chrome. **Edit:** Nevermind, I get the "Access Denied" page, so I am unable to tell .

Comment: I have added one of the missing request on the original post. I don't think there is any credential to access the link: `https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195`

Comment: Yeah, I suppose they are blocking me based on my location (from Europe) or blacklisted my IP when I launched your snippet as their system recognized me as a bot. Anyway, the issue can be checked in general. I will take another look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did some benchmarking between 4 variants of this script. And for me the results were the same. *Note:* I did multiple tests, sometimes due to local network speed it was less calls. But after 2-3 tries Puppeteer was able to catch all requests.

On the https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195 page there are some `async` and `defer` scripts, my hypothesis was that may load differently when we use different Puppeteer settings, or async vs. sync functions inside `page.on`.

*Note 2:* I tested another page, not the one in the original question as I already needed a VPN to visit this Australian website, it was easy from Chrome, with Puppeteer it would take more: trust me the page I tested has similarly tons of analytics and tracking requests.

---

## Baseline from Chrome network: 28 calls

First I've visited xy webpage, the results were **28 calls** on the *Network* tab.

## Case 1: Original (sync, networkidle2)

```js
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', (request) => {
    console.log(request.url())
    request.continue();
    ...
  }
}
await page.goto(
    'https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195',
    { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' },
  );
```

Result: **28** calls

## Case 2: Async, networkidle2

The `page.on` has an async function inside so we can await the `request.url()`

```js
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', async request => {
    console.log(await request.url())
    request.continue();
    ...
  }
}
await page.goto(
    'https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195',
    { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' },
  );
```

Result: **28** calls

## Case 3: Sync, networkidle0

Similar as the original, but with `networkidle0`.

```js
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', (request) => {
    console.log(request.url())
    request.continue();
    ...
  }
}
await page.goto(
    'https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195',
    { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' },
  );
```

Result: **28** calls

## Case 3: Async, networkidle0

The `page.on` has an async function inside so we can await the `request.url()`. Plus `networkidle0`.

```js
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', async request => {
    console.log(await request.url())
    request.continue();
    ...
  }
}
await page.goto(
    'https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195',
    { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' },
  );
```

Result: **28** calls

---

As there was no difference between the number of requests on the Network tab and from Puppeteer, neither the way we launch puppeteer or how we collect the requests my idea is:

- Either you have **accepted the Cookie Consent in your Chrome** so the Network will have more requests (these requests only happen after the cookies are accepted), you can accept their cookie policy with a simple navigation, so after you've navigated inside their page there will be more requests on Network immediately.

  > [...] By continuing to use our website, you consent to cookies being used.

**Solution:** Do not directly visit the desired page, but navigate there through clicks, so your Puppeteer's Chromium will accept the cookie consent, hence you will have all analytics requests as well.

- Some **Chrome addon** affects the number of requests on the page.

**Advise:** Check your Puppeteer requests against an incognito Chrome's Network tab, make sure all Extensions/Addons are disabled.

---

+ If you are only interested in **XHR** then you may need to add `request.resourceType` to your code to differentiate them from others [docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.3.0&show=api-httprequestresourcetype).

Comment: I appreciate your thorough explaination on that. The call I found is about 148 requests and I found if I send too many requests during a short period, I can't get all the requests. It is probably the website has some security check on the origin source.