# Node js intercept incoming ajax requests from given url

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I found this function from another stackoverflow post:

```
(function() {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        console.log('request started!');
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            console.log('request completed!');
            console.log("Server status code: ", this.status); 
            console.log("Ready state: ", this.readyState); 
            console.log("Server response:", this.responseText);
        });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

Essentially, the function can be pasted in the console of a webpage and log out all incoming ajax requests.

Is there a way I can execute this function from node js and pass in a url from a particular website that I want incoming ajax data from?

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph where you try to explain what you're attempting to accomplish.  This is client-side code.  You can't execute that in nodejs.

Comment: For example, if I go to coinmarketcap.com and paste the function in the console, It will log out incoming requests. I want to be able to execute the function from a script where I can pass in the url of a website (such as coinmarketcap.com) and it logs out the incoming requests in my terminal. I get that this is client side code but I want to be able to execute it as a regular function from a script but cant figure it out.

Comment: You can add this to the console with Puppeteer's `page.evaluate()`. You've tagged it puppeteer but there's no indication that you have it running or that you're really using it. Puppeteer also provides special ways of logging all requests with `page.on("request", ...)`. See [How can I get all xhr calls in puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62338605/how-can-i-get-all-xhr-calls-in-puppeteer)